# Template arguments in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I was reading template basics and how to pass arguments to functions using templates. The below program I tried and is running fine without any compilation error. The function  is modifying the value passed to it but `rx` and `cx` are constants and they cannot be modified. So , there should be a compilation error thrown by the compiler.

Output coming :

```
Param before : 27
Param after : 23
Param before : 27
Param after : 23
Param before : 27
Param after : 23
```

Below is the complete code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
//void f(const T& param) // param is now a ref-to-const
void f(T param) 
{
  cout << "Param before : "  <<  param << endl;
  param = 23;
  cout << "Param after : "  <<  param << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int x = 27;
  const int cx = x;
  const int& rx = x; // as before

  // as before
  // // as before

  f(x); // T is int, param's type is const int&
  f(cx); // T is int, param's type is const int&
  f(rx); // T is int, param's type is const int&
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `T` is `int` why would `T param` be `const int&`?

Comment: For `T == int` and `T param` you get `int param` which is a modifiable copy of whatever you pass in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When function parameters are defined to be passed *by value*, as is `param` in your function template `f`:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T param) // <-- note T, and not T&
```

A *type decay* occurs and as a result the `const` qualifier is discarded. This  "disqualification" makes sense since is actually a *copy* what is being passed to the function and **not** the *original object* (e.g.: the original object may be `const`, but its copy doesn't have to).

---

> The function is modifying the value passed to it but `rx` and `cx` are constants and they cannot be modified.

Because of the type decay mentioned above, in your three cases `T` is deduced to be `int` (i.e.: unqualified). The function is actually modifying a non-`const` copy of the object being passed. Therefore, you don't see any compilation error.

Comment: So, const int& and int are interchangable ?

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla No.

Comment: So, you are saying const int cx is copied into an integer in a function call ?

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla The copy is forced by the function signature being `void(T)`. If the function was `void(T&)` or `void(T const&)` it would behave differently.

Answer (score 3):

Each usage of `f` is modifying a *copy* of the value passed to it. None of those copies are `const &`, so modifying them is perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

With `T` from the the template parameter, `const`, `volatile` and `&` are removed. Same rule applies to `auto`. This is called type decaying.

So in every case only one function is used
`void f (int param)`.

```
 f(x); // argument is int, T is int, param's type is int
 f(cx); // argument is const int, T is int, param's type is int 
 f(rx); // argument is const int &, T is int, param's type int
```